# I forgot W2K3 admin password. Is it possible to reset it

Tags: windows-server-2003, password-recovery

I forgot W2K3 admin password. Is it possible to reset it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tool you need is:

http://pogostick.net/~pnh/ntpasswd/

This works to reset or blank the password.

Comment: As long as the disks aren't encrypted...

Comment: This is your best bet, as it seems your VM isn't a DC.

Comment: thx a lot it worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

I use [Ophcrack](http://ophcrack.sourceforge.net/).  It is a live CD that will tell you what the password is so that you don't have to reset it.

Comment: I have used this in the past also and was going to suggest it.  It has never failed me...+1

Comment: Interesting. How long does it take to crack a complicated password? Does it brute force or use algorithmic weakness to decrypt it?

Comment: On XP it takes about 6 minutes to find all the passwords on decent hardware.  Vista takes more like 15.  The Ophcrack website explains how it works in great detail, it quite interesting.